Plugging JsonSchema.Net into ASP.NET Core for validation
We want to make use of JsonSchema.Net to validate json sent to ASP.NET Core endpoints (Minimal APIs). Results for failures must also be returned in the RFC ProblemDetails format. This is doable but required jumping through a few hoops;

Adding the ValidatingJsonConverter to the JsonSerializerOptions Converters used by Minimal APIs (builder.Services.ConfigureHttpJsonOptions)
Creating an exception handler that could build the ProblemDetails result from the JsonException thrown by JsonSchema.Net

app.UseExceptionHandler(exceptionHandlerApp
    => exceptionHandlerApp.Run(async context =>
    {
        IExceptionHandlerFeature feature = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>() ?? throw new Exception("Unable to get error feature");

        if (feature.Error.InnerException is JsonException e && e.Data["validation"] is EvaluationResults validationResults && validationResults.HasDetails)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string[]> errors = validationResults.Details.Where(detail => detail.HasErrors).ToDictionary(detail => detail.InstanceLocation.ToString(), detail =>
            {
                return detail.Errors!.Select(error => error.Value).ToArray();
            });

            await Results.ValidationProblem(errors).ExecuteAsync(context);
        }
    }));


Manually building a schema
 public static readonly JsonSchema InvokeRequestSchema =
     new JsonSchemaBuilder()
             .Type(SchemaValueType.Object)
             .Required("appUserId")
             .Properties(
                  ("appUserId", new JsonSchemaBuilder()
                      .Type(SchemaValueType.String)
                      .Format(Formats.Uuid)
                  )
             );


Applying that schema to our DTO with the [JsonSchema] attribute
[JsonSchema(typeof(InvokeRequest), nameof(InvokeRequestSchema))]
public class InvokeRequest



This all works
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc9110#section-15.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "errors": {
        "/appUserId": [
            "Value does not match format \"uuid\""
        ]
    }
}

Would I be correct in saying a better practice would be to generate the schema from the type (using e.g FromType<>(InvokeRequest)) ahead of time, writing that JSON schema to disk and then parsing it back in on application startup to use for validation?

I prefer the hard-coded version.  It's static and very explicitly defines the model in a way that infers intent.  Secondly, you can fine-tune schemas build by hand (whether hard-coded using the builder or hand-written in JSON/YAML).  Generation might not always get things exactly how you want.
That said, the hard-coded approach isn't going to update when you change your models.  Having a build process that generates from the models and saves as external files could be valuable.  It really depends on what you want and what's easier for you.
If the generated schemas are sufficient for your needs, then I'd go that route.  I'd also use some kind of periodic manual check or verification tests (e.g. using something like Verify) to ensure that the generation is doing what you expect.

Also, regarding the errros that you return, please have a read of my blog post, Interpreting JSON Schema Output.  It can be tricky trying to figure out which errors are pertinent to a failure or useful to the user.

Would I be correct in saying that a generated schema that might not give me exactly what I want could however be corrected via attributes? If that's the case, I think we'd like to try just generating from types at runtime. Basically, we're looking at Json schema to avoid the shortcomings of the standard ASP.NET attribute validation system and this would give us a similar workflow (that we might change later).

Attributes might get you what you need.  If they do, that's great.  My point is to verify that they do.  (Also, if you do generate at runtime, cache the results.  Don't repeated generate the same schema.)
